# How to rearrange vectors in cross product?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I have an equation: $\vec{v}=\vec{w}\times \vec{r}$ How to I separate the $\vec{w}$ and write it in terms of $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{r}$?

I tried to re-arrange this equation so that I could find the direction of $\vec w$ as the direction of other two are given.

Comment: I tried to re-arrange this equation so that I could find the direction of $\vec{w}$, as the direction of other two are given

Comment: In general it's not possible because the map $\vec{w} \mapsto \vec{w} \times \vec{r}$ is not injective. (i.e it is possible to have two different $\vec{w}$ which after you take cross product, give the same result). For example, we have that for any $t \in \Bbb{R}$, $(e_x + t e_y) \times e_y = e_z$, so it possible to have infinitely many $w$ with the same output. More generally, for any $t \in \Bbb{R}$, we have $(\vec{w} + t \vec{r}) \times \vec{r} = \vec{w} \times \vec{r} = v$. i.e we still have infinitely many things with the same output.

Comment: $\vec w$ is not uniquely defined in terms of $\vec v$ and $\vec r$.

Comment: Sometimes a search is all it takes.

Comment: @AndrewChin does it have two or multiple possibilities?

Comment: @AndrewChin here's the origonal problem https://ibb.co/tMGs97Y

Comment: @Rifat You are complicating the problem too much. Both angular velocity and angular acceleration are along $z$ axis (can be either positive or negative)

Comment: @Andrei thank you ♥